# Symfony2/Doctrine: Reuse Unique base Entity for inheritance entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

In my Software i have three entities: Person, Teacher and Examiner with the following structure:

```
<?php

class Person
{

    protected $id;

    protected $firstname;

    protected $lastname;
}

class Teacher extends Person
{
    protected $subjects;
}

class Examiner extends Person
{
    protected $certificates;
}
```

Here is my Problem: I planned to use **JOINED Class Table** for inheritance and i would like Person to be a unique entity. But i would like to reuse it as well for Examiner as for Teacher. So that i have **two diffrent entities Examiner and Teacher**, but **one base Entity Person for both of them**.

In example:

```
Person | id | firstname | lastname
       | 1  | Emile     | Example

Teacher | id | subjects
        |  1 | Math, Religion, English   <--- Inheritance of Person with id 1

Examiner | id | certificate
         | 1  | Bachelor of Science   <--- Inheritance of Person with id 1, too
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this with Doctrine annotations? I dont like the idea of having the entity person as relation of both explicit classes. I prefere to reproduce a real world szenario, so that e.g. a teacher does not have a person rather he is a person.

Hope anyone got an idea about what i like to achieve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should declare an abstract MappedSuperClass "human" for instance that holds the common attributes and methods. It won't be persisted in database.

Then declare person, teacher and examiner that inherit human and declare their own specific attributes and methods. That's the concrete tables that will be stored in database.

This should help: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Regards.